# Какой подход использовать для AI в RTS?

Tags: разработка-игр, любой-язык, искусственный-интеллект

Интерсует суть - как лучше за это дело приниматься. У меня в голове 2 идеи:

1. Четкий набор инструкций в виде дерева
2. Самообучение в процессе игры вида "ты так - значит и я так, получается хуже - плохой ход, больше так не буду, получается лучше - хороший, надо запомнить и использовать его".

Подскажите, если кто-то решал подобные задачи.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Существует подход по использованию нейронных сетей, которые тренируются на последовательности (LSTM, RNN и т.п.), для стратегических игр. При этом под "последовательностью" понимается серия ходов игроков. Пример: [A Scalable Neural Network Architecture for Board Games](http://www.idsia.ch/~juergen/cig2008go.pdf). Вообще по искусственному интеллекту много хорошего материала здесь: [Artificial Intelligence](http://www.idsia.ch/~juergen/ai.html).

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте [конечные автоматы](http://kumo.spb.ru/article/ai-practics-481.html)

А вообще есть хорошая [книга](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/3384783/) на эту тему

Comment: В книге все больше про FPS, вроде, не? Но это не суть важно, конечно

Answer (score 1):

На [Udacity](http://www.udacity.com) есть замечательный [курс](https://www.udacity.com/course/cs271), посвящённый искусственным интеллектам. Правда, там не для игр, а в общем.